# How to add elements into a List in Java/Selenium

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver, stream, testng

Page Link :- https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/offers

I want to add the elements(Veg/Fruit name) into a List and want to print the list by clicking on "Next" Button  , but I am getting

Error as : java.lang.NullPointerException , at the line(**veggieList1.add(element);**)

CODE:

```
    public void seleniumStream1() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/offers");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    WebElement next1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[aria-label='Next']"));
    List<WebElement> veggieList1 = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        List<WebElement> veggies1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[1]"));

        for (WebElement element : veggies1) {
            veggieList1.add(element);
        }

        if (next1.getAttribute("aria-disabled").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            next1.click();
        }
    }

    for (WebElement element1 : veggieList1) {
        System.out.println(element1.toString());
    }
    driver.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the `veggieList1` to `null` on line `List<WebElement> veggieList1 = null;`. You should use `List<WebElement> veggieList1 = new ArrayList<>();` if you wish to initialize this variable with an empty list.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code accordingly, but now I am getting another error:                   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document                                                                                      at the line  when I try to print the elements.                                                                                                                                        for(WebElement element1: veggieList1) {
   System.out.println(element1.getText());
  }

Comment: That line is not in the code that you posted, but I recommend looking at the documentation of `getText()` if that throws an exception.

Comment: Apology, I have used get Text () only , but getting the error.